# How to mock Express JWT unless function?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs, express-jwt

I'm using Express and Express-JWT.

In a Express() instance I use:

```
const api = express()
api.use(jwt({
 // my options
}))
```

To mock this in tests, I use a `mocks\express-jwt\index.js` file containing:

```
const jwt = jest.fn().mockImplementation(options => (req, res, next) => {
  // set dummy req.user and call
  next()
})

module exports = jwt
```

This all works fine.
Now I want to skip JWT for the root endpoint, so I changed the jwt usage to:

```
api.use(jwt({
  // my options
}).unless({path:['/']}))
```

In my mock file I added:

```
jwt.unless = jest.fn().mockImplementation(options => (req, res, next) => {
  next()
})
```

However, the tests now always fail with `function unless is not defined`.

Anyone an idea how to mock this `unless` behaviour?

Comment: where unless comes from? from this? `express-unless`

Answer (score 1):

`unless` is being used as a property *on the result of calling `jwt`*.

So to mock it, add your `unless` mock as a property of the function returned by your `jwt` mock:

```
const jwt = jest.fn().mockImplementation(options => {
  const func = (req, res, next) => {
    // set dummy req.user and call
    next();
  };
  func.unless = jest.fn().mockImplementation(options => (req, res, next) => {
    next();
  });
  return func;
});

module.exports = jwt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested answer by Brian did not work for me, because in the `func` method I do some stuff for faking an authorization check.
My problem was I needed to do skip the authorization check for the method+path given in by the `unless` function.

My solution now is like this:

```
const jet = jest.fn(options => {
  let mockFunc = (req, res, next) => {
    // get authorization from request
    let token = ...

    if (!token) {
      res.status(401).send('No token provided')
    } else {
      req.token = token
      next()
    }
  }

  mockFunc.unless = jest.fn(args => (req, res, next) => {
    if (args.method == req.method && arg.path == req.path) {
      // not do authorization check for excluded endpoint via unless
      next()
    else {
      mockFunc(req, res, next)
    }
  }

  return mockFunc
}
```

Thanks to Brian for pointing me in the right direction.